# Using Return View(...) can we pass model and querystring in the same call?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344377/how-to-return-view-with-querystring-in-asp-net-mvc-2) link and am facing the same problem, which is not resolved.

So here is the simple thing,I have the below code:

```
return View("ResetPassword", resetPasswordModel);
```

Now, along with model, I want to pass a query string which should get appended in the URL.
Is there any way to pass the model as well as query string in the same call?Please remember, I m gonna redirect to this view, not to another action method.(So RedirectToAction won't work!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to change the url, you need to redirect (and you redirect back to the same view using `RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", new { .... })`

Answer (score -1):

You can use Viewbag to send any type of data to the view from controller like this:

ViewBag.QueryString = "Your query string";

Here, you can write any good name instead of QueryString.

The way you get it in the view is like this:

@ViewBag.QueryString

See this MSDN post
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Nab, I know how to store and retrieve the value using Viewbag, but I want the query string values to be appended in the actual URL when the View is being generated!

Comment: to achieve this, i would call another action from the first action and pass those data in the query string and call the view from that 2nd action action.